# How to draw a UML diagram when class A has aggregation and composition relationship with class B?

Tags: java, uml, aggregation, composition

I have two questions to ask. So let's assume there's a class A and B which are defined like these.

1.

```
class A {
    private B b;
    private B otherB;
    public A(B otherB)
    {
        this.otherB = otherB; 
    }
}
class B {
}
```

So class A has a composition relationship with the variable b and aggregation relationship with the variable otherB. How can I draw this in UML diagram.

2.Would the following case be still a composition relationship?

```
class A
{
    private B b;
    public B getMethod(){
        B newB = new B();
        newB.bValue = b.bValue;
        return newB;
    }  
}
class B
{
    private int bValue;
}
```

Comment: No. It's not a question from assignment or school. I read upon the association relationship and I wanted to be more clear how it would work in the above situation.

Comment: What aggregation / composition are you referring to? All I can see is two simple directional associations from A to B (one named `b` and the other named `otherB`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As other comments/replies have pointed out, there is not problem of having different associations (composed or not) between the same classes.
   [image: composition vs aggregation]
2. From the implementation point of view (and this also applies to the previous question) you need to understand what a [composition association means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Composition).

Basically, if we have instance specification **a1** and **a2** (as instances of the class **A**), only one of them could compose an instance **b1** (as instance of the class **B**) via the role (association end) "composesB" of the composite association.

Likewise, provided that **a1** composes **b1** via the "composesB" role of a composite association, everytime **a1** gets "destroyed", **b1** should also be "destroyed". Instead, this wouldn´t occur if **a1** object aggregated **b1** via the "aggregatesB" role of an aggregate association.

As you may imagine, from an implementation point of view, you need much more than a field and a simple method in a class in order to support a composite association between two classes.

**Update: to include an example.**

For example, EMF is an implementation of the [EMOF](http://goo.gl/4LrtSO) specification (it´s not UML) in which the concept of a containment reference (similar to the concept of a composite association) can be depicted as follows. In our particular case:

[image: Generated code for a composite reference]

Going away from technical details, you may grasp that when you set a B instance as part (contained, composed) by an A instance object. You firstly have to check that the former might be contained in a different A instance via the same containment reference, if so, such B instance needs to be removed from the old A instance one.

Comment: 1. Two  different instances of A cannot both be composed from a single instance of B. Agreed.

Comment: 2. If a1 is composed from b1, then destroying a1 should also destroy b1. This is the most basic definition of composition. According to Wikipedia, this is not a strict requirement, however: “Note that, where allowed, a part can be removed from a composite before the composite is deleted, and thus not be deleted as part of the composite.”

Comment: 3. You say, “This wouldn´t occur if a1 object aggregates b2.” Why not? Aggregating b2 does not affect the lifecycle of b1 (though, again, destruction of b1 is not strictly required, according to Wikipedia).

Comment: 4. “You need much more than a field and a simple method in a class in order to support a composite association.” Please provide a reference for this assertion, or at least an example.

Comment: @jaco0646 comment2. IMO, it means that you could "remove" (not composed anymore) b1 as a composed element (and for instance be part of an a2 element), prior to delete a1, so that b1 is not lost.

Comment: @jaco0646 comment3. I´ve edited my response replacing b2 by b1 which created the confussion. The key point is that b1 may be associacited with many a1, a2, etc instances and if any of them is deleted, b1 would not be deleted.

Comment: @jaco0646 comment4. I´ve added an example with some generated code for a tool to depict the cornerstones of a composite association. Basically, every time you set an object as part of another via a containment reference. Extra logic needs to be added to keep consistent of a composite association semantics.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I agree with all of it. However, I don't believe it addresses the OP's question. The question is how to ensure composition when you *instantiate* one object as part of another. Your code example shows how to ensure composition when you *set* one object as part of another. Setting is much more complicated, as it requires e.g. a notification mechanism between the caller and receiver. My understanding of this question is that b1 would be instantiated inside of A, not passed in. The only question of composition is that b1 does not get out, thus the defensive copy.

Comment: @jaco0646. My response to 2 was a gentle answer to say "no". getMethod() is clearly not implementing a composite association. Returning a new object with the same value than the object it´s really "composing", it´s just a bad smell. Nothing to relate to a composite association implementation. For instance, every returned "newB" would be around the system when the A instance which created them were "deleted".

Answer (score 0):

1. [Creating Multiple Associations Between Classes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21325919) is, in fact, legal. The recommendation is to assign a role to each relationship when you do so.
2. I'm going to say yes, that is still a composition relationship (though others may disagree). To make my case, we look at the simple IBM [definition](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdvhelp/v6r0m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc%2Ftopics%2Fccompasn.html) showing Student composed of Schedule (presumably amongst other things). It's very easy to imagine that there would also be a Teacher composed of Schedule, and that a Teacher might want to get the Schedule of a Student, or vice versa. Does the getting of a Schedule by another class invalidate the composition relationship? I think not; or at least, the IBM definition does not appear to be so narrow as to preclude that possibility.